# Why does \hspace{50mm} not exactly add 50 mm of horizontal space?

Tags: spacing

I wanted to write a line that must be 250 mm from the top and should be at 50 mm from the left side, to do that following is my code.

I have used `\vspace*` to get the margin from top at the start of the page and `\hspace` to get a horizontal margin.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage[a4paper, margin = 0in]{geometry}

    \begin{document}
          \vspace*{250mm} % using to get a margin from top
          \hspace{50mm} I am at 250 mm from Top and 50 mm from left side.
    \end{document}
```

Which is giving me the below output.

The text is 250 mm from the top but leaves a margin of an extra 10 mm from the left side, i.e. a total of **60 mm** margin from the left side.

[image: LaTeX Image]

Comment: `\noindent\hspace{50mm}`

Comment: Thanks! will it also remove the space between **\hspace{}** and **I**? I have not checked it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three spaces, an indentation from the start of a paragraph (actually a box not a space), the 50mm space, then a variable word-space coming from the space token you added between `\hspace{}` and `I`

`\showoutput` will show:

```
...\glue(\baselineskip) 6.16669
...\hbox(8.33331+2.33331)x597.50787, glue set 161.76242fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x17.62482                  % paragraph indent
....\glue 142.26378                          % requested space
....\glue 3.91663 plus 1.95831 minus 1.30554 % inter-word space
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 I
....\glue 3.91663 plus 1.95634 minus 1.30684
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 a
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 m
```

Comment: Will **\noindent\hspace{50mm}** (as suggested by @egreg above) remove the third space (between **\hspace{}** and **I**)?

Comment: @Pushpendra No, you need to not add the space. In a real document you should almost never have vspace or hspace so this hardly ever a problem in practice

Comment: Thank you so much.